# how to remove hostname and timestamp from logs coming from remote syslog server

Tags: linux, syslog, splunk, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I am using rsyslog to send all syslog files and few additional application log files to remote syslog server which has syslog-ng server running and it's sending to Splunk using splunk forwarder. My problem is, when rsyslog sending logs to remote syslog server (syslog-ng), in log events it's adding Timestamp and Hostname to it. How do I tell rsyslog to don't add Timestamp and Hostname to any log events?
based on my findings, there is a template in rsyslog.conf. where we can define format and other things about log events. I tried that but it didn't work.

in my rsyslog.conf I have entry for template as,

```
$template noTimeStampFormat,"%syslogtag% %msg%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate noTimeStampFormat
```

I restarted syslog service, this change didn't work.

can someone please help me here on how to fix this?

Currently events looks like

```
<timestamp> <hostname> <tag> sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
```

Ideal would be,

```
<tag> sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ActionFileDefaultTemplate is a legacy command. If you are mixing it with newer-style Rainer script like `action(...)` it has no effect. Also, forwarding probably uses template `RSYSLOG_TraditionalForwardFormat`. Use an explicit template in your rules, eg perhaps for legacy it is `*.* @@server;noTimeStampFormat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me.  We use dynaFiles to do hostname based files.
I had a need to remove timestamp and hostname from being prefixed to events already formatted in JSON.

```
template (name="LOG_TYPE_PATH" type="string"
  string="/path/to/your/logs/LOG_TYPE/%HOSTNAME%.log")

template(name="noTimestamp" type="list") {
    property(name="syslogtag")
    property(name="msg" spifno1stsp="on" )
    property(name="msg" droplastlf="on" )
    constant(value="\n")
    }

if ($hostname contains "10.0.0.17") then {
  action(type="omfile" dynaFile="LOG_TYPE_PATH" template="noTimestamp")
}
```

These links were helpful:

https://serverfault.com/questions/1042248/rsyslog-8-dynafile-with-a-template
https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation where I'm logging to a local syslog and then forwarding all local0 facility entries over to a Graylog syslog input.

This is an example /etc/rsyslog.d/60-graylog.conf

```
template(name="MyFormat" type="string"
     string= "%syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"
    )

local0.* @1.2.3.4:10514;MyFormat
```

(That last line is in "legacy" format and should really be rewritten with the "action" syntax)

More info and template properties are available at https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html

Answer (score -4):

on linux command line:

`cut -d$' ' -f 3-20 logfile.log >newfile.log`

"cut" splits in parts delimited by ' ' (space) and output part 3 to 20  ;)